# Worldbuilding is misleading

Tags: feature-request

It's not Worldbuilding.  It's fictional fantasy that uses a misleading title.  I tried to pose a question based on reality, and was told this is a fictional site that is more about Hobbitworld Building. That said, it should be under Fantasy.   It's very misleading.  There are other titles that could apply but Worldbuilding is very misleading.  See the latest posts under it.  Not just mine either.

Comment: Did you delete the question you asked? Without being able to see it I can't know for sure, but questions based on reality are usually quite acceptable here. Most answers are also based on reality. While we do feature a lot of fantasy questions, for the most part we tend to focus less on magic and more on science.

Comment: If you're trying to vent...mission accomplished.  If there is supposed to be a question or critique could you clarify what you are suggesting or asking?

Comment: You missed the point.  It's a bogus title.

Comment: This category was created for people who like to play games.

Comment: @Daaadooosh    sorry, no.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh link to the "question" (deleted): http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39399/worldbuilding-is-nonsense

Comment: Thank you.  You'll get yours.

Comment: Is that a threat...cause I must tell you I am just *terrified*

Comment: @TimSpriggs, just FYI, I recall we have a perfectly serviceable question on [star-building](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/how-could-a-civilization-trigger-star-formation).

Comment: I find your premise to be ridiculous. World building is the exact topic of this site, it means creating _fictional_ worlds. It doesn't belong completely under fantasy, because some people wa t to use science, hence making it science fiction, not fantasy. Also, on your question (since deleted) you said to tell you when we build a world. Well, I'm guessing you yourself have built an imaginary world before unless you are a heartless robot or a mindless drone.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to take a leaf from one of the comments to your deleted question and post a link to the [Wikipedia page on Worldbuilding](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldbuilding). The definition there offers a broader understanding of the term, for instance "Worldbuilding often involves the creation of maps, a backstory, and people for the world". These are all things which we answer questions about here.

It looks like your deleted question wasn't actually a question, that's why it was downvoted. If you actually wanted to literally build a planet, you could probably ask about that, and if your question was suitably constrained it would probably get upvoted and receive good answers. We have many such questions.

And I think you're taking Tolkien in much the wrong direction. The world he created may have been fictional, and contained some fantasy elements, but it was also constructed using knowledge of ancient cultures and stories. Middle-Earth is a world built with care and filled with intricate detail; there are many people who know more about its geography, history, or cultures than they do about those of their own world. This is why Tolkien is a great model for what we do here at Worldbuilding: because even though the world he created was full of fictional fantastical Hobbits, it still obeyed some fundamental laws that readers could understand and associate with. Middle Earth makes sense, and it has life and meaning beyond any one story that takes place upon it. This is what we strive for here, worlds that feel real and immerse the audience. We ask how to build such worlds, and if that's not called Worldbuilding, then I'd really like to know what it should be called.